# Mathematica cannot evaluate the real part of a fraction?

Tags: complex

I am encountering some confusing behaviour with Mathematica that maybe you can help me resolve:

If I type:

```
Im[1/a]~Refine~(a \[Element] Reals)
```

I get the output:

```
Im[1/a]
```

Which seems incorrect to me. Surely if a is a real number, then 1/a is also a real number?
But if I type:

```
Im[1/a]~Refine~(a > 0)
```

Then I get the correct answer, 0. I get zero if I refine a<0 too.
What is the meaning of this?

Comment: `Im[1/a] // ComplexExpand` returns `0`. Maybe the problem is that `a` could be `0` and `1/0` evaluates to `ComplexInfinity`. And `Im[ComplexInfinity]` evluates to `Indeterminate` which is not equal to `0`.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Mathematica sure does have it's quirks!

Comment: `Im[1/a]~Refine~(a \[Element] Reals && a != 0)`